# Can you recommend and explain a less verbose get/set syntax?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, get, set

I'm following a tutorial about making a hierarchical state machine, and it's also my first real attempt at heavily using getters and setters. If you look at my script linked below, you'll notice that the getters and setters take up as much space as the declarations themselves, if not more. Maybe it's just my inexperience, but I personally find this hard to read and follow.

I use Rider as my IDE and it occasionally will suggest 'auto-properties' instead, but when I use them I don't always understand the result and my googling has just made me more confused. I'm just wondering if there is a less verbose, more human readable way to implement getters and setters without all the duplication.

https://hastepaste.com/view/gXut7I9

Comment: [Auto Implemented Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties)

Comment: Yes, use auto properties.  `but when I use them I don't always understand the result` - what don't you understand about them?

Comment: @Jonesopolis For example, why am I unable to use auto-properties for `CurrentMovementY` and `AppliedMovementY`?

Comment: @GeraldChristie because the contain not a "simple" assignment to underlying field logic.

Comment: If your properties' code is like your example (exactly what auto props do) then use auto props. That's just boilerplate; IMHO, you need a reason to not use them.